# MySQL Full table scan

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok,on the following query DMSNODE has 144K rows. and there is an index on CHANGEDON, ID, PARENT ID and 2 permutations of the 3

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT t0.ID AS a1,
    t0.CHANGEDON,
    t1.id AS a2
FROM
    DMSNODE t0
    LEFT OUTER JOIN DMSNODE t1 ON (t1.ID = t0.PARENT_ID)
ORDER BY
    t0.CHANGEDON ASC
LIMIT
     0, 5
```

This is the table definition

```
CREATE TABLE `dmsnode` (
    `ID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,    
    `PARENT_ID` BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `TITLE` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
    `CHANGEDON` DATETIME NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    KEY `DMSNODE_PARENT_ID_FK` (`PARENT_ID`),
    KEY `DMSNODE_CHANGEDON_IDX` (`CHANGEDON`),
    KEY `idx_dmsnode_ID_PARENT_ID_CHANGEDON` (`ID` , `PARENT_ID` , `CHANGEDON`),
    KEY `idx_dmsnode_ID_PARENT_ID` (`ID` , `PARENT_ID`),

    CONSTRAINT `DMSNODE_FOLDER_ID_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`PARENT_ID`)
        REFERENCES `dmsnode` (`ID`),
    )  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 COMMENT='DMS Node'
```

And EXPLAIN shows a full table scan

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      t0      index   ""idx_dmsnode_ID_PARENT_ID_CHANGEDON    25  ""  144982  Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE      t1      eq_ref  PRIMARY,idx_dmsnode_ID_PARENT_ID_CHANGEDON,idx_dmsnode_ID_PARENT_ID PRIMARY 8   tbibms.t0.PARENT_ID 1   Using index
```

Can someone explain to why a full table scan is performed and how to avoid it? I thought that with the index on CHANGEDON would be enough to first select the top 5 changedon rows and then do the left outer join

Comment: It's probably the DISTINCT. Is it really needed or can you remove it or move it into a Derived Table?

Answer (score 0):

There's no WHERE clause in your query so the database engine has to look at every row in both of these tables. In such a case a full table scan will result in less I/O than using an index.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: i was trying to simplify the problem. the where clause is on another left join not in the example which uses indexes. the actual query is: select top 5 records from a left join b where a doesn't have any matching records on b. is there any way to do that without a full table scan Bob?

Comment: Please edit the question and include the full query. Many of the developers on StackOverflow are good, but according to my crystal ball none of us are mind-readers. :-) Thanks.